# vue-form-wizard beforeTabChange callback not being called

Tags: vue.js, formwizard

I have a simple three question onboarding form, I am trying to use the wizard for.

beforeTabSwitch does not appear to be called when I switch between the form elements. Here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div>
   ...
    <form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete">
      <tab-content title="Location">
        <p>looks like you're at {{address}}, correct?</p>
        <b-form role="form" @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(login)">
          <base-input alternative
                      class="mb-3"
                      name=""
                      :rules="{required: true}"
                      prepend-icon="ni ni-pin-3"
                      v-model="address">
          </base-input>
        </b-form>
      </tab-content>
      ...
        <div class="mt-3">Selected: <strong>{{ selected }}</strong></div>
      </tab-content>
    </form-wizard>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
...
  methods: {
    onComplete: function(){
      alert(this.$store.state.auth.userPrefs.genre);
    },
    beforeTabSwitch: function(){
      alert("This is called before switching tabs")

      return true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you bind the `before-change` prop to anything (supposedly the `beforeTabSwitch` method)?

Comment: I did not realize that was required. something like this: :before-change="beforeTabSwitch" ok now I see that. missed that in the example. thanks very much. If you put that in an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Glad it was an easy fix. 